# Google is not indexing images

Tags: xml-sitemap

Hi

Everyday my scripts submit a xml to Google, containing new pages as well the images associated to them.

The pages are indexed ok but not the images.

For example, if I type in Google Web Search "Camisa Malha Cavalinhos", the first result is https://www.ebraz.co/listing.php?id=1052, which is ok.

But when I turn to Image Search, no results from my site are returned.

Robots.txt is not disallowing the images folder.

Below is the xml (headers [no longer] omitted).

What can I possibly be doing wrong?

Please ask for more details if you need. Thanks.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<urlset xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'
xmlns:xhtml='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
xmlns:image='http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1'>
<url>
<loc>https://www.ebraz.co/listing.php%3Fid%3D1052%26title%3DCamisa+Malha+Cavalinhos</loc>
<image:image>
<image:loc>https://www.ebraz.co/upload/o_19la610uf1hpi1cuc11n2e801qc915.jpg</image:loc>
<image:title>Camisa Malha Cavalinhos</image:title>
</image:image>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

On the page: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en

You will notice this one begins with the xml version line.  Also it doesn't have the xhtml line in it.  I would modify it to be identical to this example from google.  I have previously seen non-identical versions having issues.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
 <url>
   <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>
   <image:image>
     <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
   </image:image>
   <image:image>
     <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
   </image:image>
 </url> 
</urlset>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I said that the headers were omitted. I edited it now to full version. Also, I am going to try removing the xhtml line.

Comment: I saw that, wasn't sure if it matched perfectly.  How long ago did you submit the first time?

Comment: No problem. It has been submitted once a day for several months (at least two for this particular page).